# Why does an overridden non-client area show the default when the window loses focus on win32?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a overridden the non-client area of my window, in the window's callback function, as follows:

```
    case WM_NCPAINT:
    {
        HDC hdc;
        RECT rect;
        HPEN pen;

        hdc=GetDCEx(hWnd,(HRGN)wParam,DCX_WINDOW|DCX_CACHE|DCX_INTERSECTRGN|DCX_LOCKWINDOWUPDATE);
        GetWindowRect(hWnd,&rect);
        pen=CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 10, RGB(255, 0, 0));//red pen 10 pixels in size
        SelectObject(hdc,pen);
        Rectangle(hdc,0,0,(rect.right-rect.left),(rect.bottom-rect.top));
        DeleteObject(pen);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd,hdc);
        RedrawWindow(hWnd,&rect,(HRGN)wParam,RDW_UPDATENOW)
    }break;
```

That does the trick and in the case above draws a red rectangle around my window.
However, if the window loses focus, then the default non-client area is painted and my custom non-client area drawing disappear.

I have tried catching the message WM_KILLFOCUS in my window's callback function and do the same with it as I do with WM_NCPAINT but it didn't do anything (although I saw I receive this message when I press on another window and my window losses focus).

What am I missing here...?

Comment: NC painting is not so simple, theming made it impractical.  Plenty of problems.  Your DeleteObject() call does *not* delete the object.  It is selected in the device context.  You *must* restore the DC.  Save the return value from SelectObject() and call SelectObject again after painting to restore the old pen.  Afaict, your code ought to burn 100% core, RedrawWindow causes WM_NCPAINT to be generated again.  Don't help too much, WM_PAINT gets the job done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a handler for `WM_NCACTIVATE`:

```
case WM_NCACTIVATE:
    // Paint the non-client area now, otherwise Windows will paint its own
    RedrawWindow(hWnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_UPDATENOW);
    break;
```

Comment: If I remove the `RedrawWindow` at the end of the `WM_NCPAINT` than when I re-size the window the non-client area being re-sized (the border that the mouse is holding) disappears - I don't see the default nor the custom non-client area. When I'm done re-sizing (letting the mouse go) the custom non-client area returns. If I leave the `RedrawWindow` at the end of the `WM_NCPAINT` than the custom non-client area is also drawn while re-sizing. I have checked the impact on the CPU of having the `RedrawWindow` and not having it and did not find a significant difference.